# Link error with CUDA 7.5 in Windows 10 (from Theano project): MSVCRT.lib error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: python-2.7, cuda, gpu, theano, nvcc

I am trying to properly setup CUDA in order to take advantage of the GPU in Theano.

After fixing many compilation problems by tuning my `.theanorc` and `nvcc.profile` files, I am struggling to fix this linking error:

```
mod.cu(735): warning: conversion from pointer to smaller integer    
mod.cu(1019): warning: statement is unreachable    
mod.cu(735): warning: conversion from pointer to smaller integer    
mod.cu(1019): warning: statement is unreachable    
mod.cu
Creating library C:/Users/niluje/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_60_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-2.7.10-64/cuda_ndarray/cuda_ndarray.lib and object C:/Users/niluje/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_60_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-2.7.10-64/cuda_ndarray/cuda_ndarray.exp
MSVCRT.lib(atonexit.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_EncodePointer referenced in function __atonexitinit
MSVCRT.lib(crtdll.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_EncodePointer
MSVCRT.lib(atonexit.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DecodePointer referenced in function _onexit
MSVCRT.lib(crtdll.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_DecodePointer
MSVCRT.lib(gs_report.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_IsDebuggerPresent referenced in function __raise_securityfailure
MSVCRT.lib(gs_report.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol IsProcessorFeaturePresent referenced in function __report_gsfailure
MSVCRT.lib(gs_support.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_QueryPerformanceCounter referenced in function __security_init_cookie
MSVCRT.lib(gs_support.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetCurrentProcessId referenced in function __security_init_cookie
MSVCRT.lib(gs_support.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetCurrentThreadId referenced in function __security_init_cookie
MSVCRT.lib(gs_support.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetSystemTimeAsFileTime referenced in function __security_init_cookie
MSVCRT.lib(dllmain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DisableThreadLibraryCalls referenced in function DllMain
C:/Users/niluje/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_60_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-2.7.10-64/cuda_ndarray/cuda_ndarray.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals
```

Here's my `.theanorc`file:

```
[global]
device = gpu
floatX = float32

[cuda]
root = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5

[nvcc]
flags = --use-local-env  --cl-version=2013 -LC:\Users\niluje\Anaconda\Lib;
compiler_bindir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64
```

And here is my `nvcc.profile` file:

```
TOP              = $(_HERE_)/..

NVVMIR_LIBRARY_DIR = $(TOP)/nvvm/libdevice

PATH            += $(TOP)/open64/bin;$(TOP)/nvvm/bin;$(_HERE_);$(TOP)/lib;

INCLUDES        +=  "-I$(TOP)/include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include" $(_SPACE_)

LIBRARIES        =+ $(_SPACE_) "/LIBPATH:$(TOP)/lib/$(_WIN_PLATFORM_)" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib"

CUDAFE_FLAGS    +=
PTXAS_FLAGS     +=
```

It seems that this is not an uncommon error, but generally fixes involve [changing some setting in the Visual Studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098627/how-to-integrate-cuda-cu-code-with-c-app). However, here I don't have a Visual Studio project. The code is dynamically generated by Theano and compiled at runtime.

Relevant system settings:

- Windows 10 (yes...)
- Python 2.7.10 64bits (Anaconda distrib)
- CUDA 7.5 / NVIDIA driver 353.54 / GeForce GTX 760
- Visual Studio Community 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Damn it! I figured it out just after posting the question. The solution: slightly different include and library folders:

```
TOP              = $(_HERE_)/..

NVVMIR_LIBRARY_DIR = $(TOP)/nvvm/libdevice

PATH            += $(TOP)/open64/bin;$(TOP)/nvvm/bin;$(_HERE_);$(TOP)/lib;

INCLUDES        +=  "-I$(TOP)/include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include" $(_SPACE_)

LIBRARIES        =+ $(_SPACE_) "/LIBPATH:$(TOP)/lib/$(_WIN_PLATFORM_)" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\x64"

CUDAFE_FLAGS    +=
PTXAS_FLAGS     +=
```

In particular I switched from:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\
```

to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A
```

(I thought that I had to use the `Program Files` ones because of my 64bits project, but in fact the 64bits files are also included in `Program Files (x86)`)

Comment: Thanks for posting a solution to your question

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to thank you. I have been trying to get this working for hours, and this was the post that put me over the edge. My config was slightly different, so my actual links were different. I am posting them in case it helps anyone else

.theanorc

```
[global]
device = gpu
floatX = float32

[nvcc]
flags = --use-local-env  --cl-version=2008
```

nvcc.profile

```
TOP              = $(_HERE_)/..

NVVMIR_LIBRARY_DIR = $(TOP)/nvvm/libdevice

PATH            += $(TOP)/open64/bin;$(TOP)/nvvm/bin;$(_HERE_);$(TOP)/lib;

INCLUDES        +=  "-I$(TOP)/include" "-I$(TOP)/include/cudart" "-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Microsoft/Visual C++ for Python/9.0/VC/include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include"$(_SPACE_)

LIBRARIES        =+ $(_SPACE_) "/LIBPATH:$(TOP)/lib/$(_WIN_PLATFORM_)" "/LIBPATH:C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Microsoft/Visual C++ for Python/9.0/VC/lib/amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\x64"

CUDAFE_FLAGS    +=
OPENCC_FLAGS    +=
PTXAS_FLAGS     +=
```

using:
windows 7, 64bit
cuda 5.5
python 2.7
windows SDK 7.1
Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7