# CUDA Project Structure

Tags: c++, c, cuda

The template and cppIntegration examples in the CUDA SDK (version 3.1) use Externs to link function calls from the host code to the device code.

However, Tom's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090974/how-to-separate-cuda-code-into-multiple-files#comment-2024913) indicates that the usage of extern is deprecated.

If this the case, what's the correct structure for a CUDA project such as the template example or cppIntegration example?

Comment: Not so much deprectaed, as no longer required in all cases! If you're mixing C and C++ then you'll still need it, but by the nvcc front-end uses C++ binding so to call from C++ it is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what your host code is. If you end up mixing C and C++ you still need the externs. For details see [this guide](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html).

Update: the content from the above link has been moved [here] (https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp).

Comment: Link is not available! "Forbidden. You do not have permission to access the requested file on this server."