# How to use a struct with CUDA functions on my main function (they are on different files)? How to link them? Using VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, struct, cuda

Pretty simple question, but i can't make it work...

I have this struct:

```
struct Rand48 
{
    // strided iteration constants (48-bit, distributed on 2x 24-bit)
    uint2 A, C;
    // CUDA array -- random numbers for all threads
    uint2 *state;
    // random number for a single thread (used by CUDA device functions only)
    uint2 state0;

    // magic constants for rand48
    static const unsigned long long a = 0x5DEECE66DLL, c = 0xB;

    void init(int nThreads, int seed) {
        uint2* seeds = new uint2[ nThreads ];

        cudaMalloc((void**) &state, sizeof(uint2)*nThreads);

        // calculate strided iteration constants
        unsigned long long A, C;
        A = 1LL; C = 0LL;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (unsigned int)nThreads; ++i) {
            C += A*c;
            A *= a;
        }
        this->A.x = A & 0xFFFFFFLL;
        this->A.y = (A >> 24) & 0xFFFFFFLL;
        this->C.x = C & 0xFFFFFFLL;
        this->C.y = (C >> 24) & 0xFFFFFFLL;

        // prepare first nThreads random numbers from seed
        unsigned long long x = (((unsigned long long)seed) << 16) | 0x330E;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (unsigned int)nThreads; ++i) {
            x = a*x + c;
            seeds[i].x = x & 0xFFFFFFLL;
            seeds[i].y = (x >> 24) & 0xFFFFFFLL;
        }

        cudaMemcpy(state, seeds, sizeof(uint2)*nThreads, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        delete[] seeds;
    }

    void destroy() {
        cudaFree((void*) state);
    }
};
```

It has some cuda functions, like cudamalloc, and some normal host c code.

How can i make this work? Like:

If i put this code on a `.cu` file, VS will compile it using nvcc. But then i won't have the declaration of the struct on my main.cpp file (including the `.cu` probably won'r work either).
 If i put this on a `.h` file, VS will complain that i didn't declare `int2` and all other CUDA stuff.

Where should i put this struct? How can i link this and my main?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least three ways to fix the problem.

The first is to use `nvcc` to compile your `main.cpp`, if you can.

The C++ way is to use the Pointer-To-Implementation pattern (pImpl). Basically, you'll split the `Rand48` class into two parts: the public methods stay in `Rand48`, and the only non-method member is a forward declaration for a pointer to `Impl`. This way you can put the Rand48 class in a .h You can then put the CUDA-specific code in `Rand48::Impl`, which is disconnected from the `Rand48` class body itself.

The C way is to forward declare the `Rand48` class itself (rather than `Rand48::Impl`) and also declare non-member functions which take `Rand48*`.

Comment: I found a question that made my code work. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090974/how-to-separate-cuda-code-into-multiple-files`. Also, i included the headers that declare everything Rand48 uses, and then VS accepted it. Working like a charm. Thanks.