# CUDA: VFW - CODEC DLL

Tags: c++, dll, cuda

My English is not very good and I'm sorry for that. 
I have a video codec project for windows(C++), based on VFW interface. It compiles into dll, setups  and runs successfully. 
What i want is to add CUDA kernel functions to force/improve some algorithm steps. 
I have installed SDK, toolkit and wizard. Applied CUDA rule to project. Added .cu file with my kernel function and a .cu file which represents a wrapper to kernel. 
I've also read  [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046228/how-do-i-start-a-new-cuda-app-in-visual-studio-2008/2047892#2047892) and applied all as well.

Mostly everything goes well, but I got this only

```
1>Linking..
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartuperror:
```

The type of the project was set correctly before, I can say that because the project was running well before i added .cu files, applied rules.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more details as to precisely what linker command-line is being used, but it looks like the "Subsystem" is possibly incorrect. I believe that `crtexecw.obj` is used when you're building a Windows executable - hence why it's trying to find the `WinMain` entry point.