# Trouble with building Cuda programme in VS2008: LNK2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, build, cuda, lnk2019

I am having some trouble with building my programme.  I am working on Windows 7 professional 32-bit with Visual Studio 2008.  I have the Cuda SDK and my project is set up with all links to cudart.lib etc.  My problem is when I try to build my project it returns the following errors:

> 1>crowdSim.obj : error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol
>   _setParameters referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall
>   Crowd::_create(int)"
>   (?_create@Crowd@@IAEXH@Z)
>   1>crowdSim.obj : error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol _mapBuffer
>   referenced in function "protected:
>   void __thiscall Crowd::_create(int)"
>   (?_create@Crowd@@IAEXH@Z)
>   1>crowdSim.obj : error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol
>   _allocToDevice referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall
>   Crowd::_create(int)"
>   (?_create@Crowd@@IAEXH@Z)
>   1>crowdSim.obj : error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol
>   _registerBuffer referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall
>   Crowd::_create(int)"
>   (?_create@Crowd@@IAEXH@Z)
>   1>../../bin/win32/Debug/crowd.exe :
>   fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved
>   externals

It seems my problem is with how I am setting up my "allocToDevice", "mapBuffer", "setParameters", and "registerBuffer" methods since if I comment these out I can build the project no problem.

I have defined the methods in the following files:

crowdSim.cuh:

```
    extern "C"
{
    void checkCUDAError(const char *msg);

    void setParameters(SimParams *hostParams);

    void registerBuffer(uint vbo);

    void allocToDevice(void **ptr, int memSize);

    void mapBuffer(void **ptr, uint vbo);
}
```

crowdSim.cu:

```
#include <cstdlib.h>
#include <cstdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <cuda_gl_interop.h>

// includes, kernels
#include "crowd_kernel.cu"

extern "C"
{
void checkCUDAError(const char *msg)
{
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
    if( cudaSuccess != err) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cuda error: %s: %s.\n", msg, cudaGetErrorString( err) );
        exit(-1);
    }                         
}

void setParameters(SimParams *hostParams)
{
    // copy parameters to constant memory
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(params, hostParams, sizeof(SimParams));
}

void registerBuffer(uint vbo)
{
    cudaGLRegisterBufferObject(vbo);
}



void allocToDevice(void **ptr, size_t memSize)
{
    cudaMalloc(ptr, memSize);
}

void mapBuffer(void **ptr, uint vbo)
{
    cudaGLMapBufferObject(ptr, vbo);
}
} //extern "C"
```

and they are only called from the _create method in my "Crowd" class from crowdSim.cpp:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include "crowdSim.h"
#include "crowdSim.cuh"
#include "crowd_kernel.cuh"

Crowd::Crowd(uint crowdSize) :
    //numP(crowdSize),
    hPos(0),
    hVel(0),
    dPosIn(0),
    dVelIn(0),
    dPosOut(0),
    dVelOut(0)
    {
        params.numBodies = crowdSize;
        _create(crowdSize);
    }

Crowd::~Crowd()
    {
        //_remove();
        crowdSize = 0;
    }

uint
Crowd::newVBO(uint size)
{
    GLuint vbo;
 //   glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
 //   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
 //   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, 0, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
 //   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    return vbo;
}

void
Crowd::_create(int numPeople)
{
    crowdSize = numPeople;

    unsigned int memSize = sizeof(float) * crowdSize * 4;

    hPos = new float[crowdSize*4];
    hVel = new float[crowdSize*4];

    hPos = (float*) malloc(memSize);
    hVel = (float*) malloc(memSize);

    posVbo = newVBO(memSize);

    registerBuffer(posVbo);

    allocToDevice((void**) &dPosIn, memSize);
    allocToDevice((void**) &dPosOut, memSize);
    allocToDevice((void**) &dVelIn, memSize);
    allocToDevice((void**) &dVelOut, memSize);

    mapBuffer((void**)&dPosVbo, posVbo);

    setParameters(&params);

}
```

I feel like I am missing something very basic here but I can't work out what so any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Have you added the cuda.rules file to enable Visual Studio to recognise the .cu extension? The cuda.rules teaches VS what to do with a .cu such that it will be compiled and linked. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046228/how-do-i-start-a-new-cuda-app-in-visual-studio-2008/2047892#2047892) for more information on setting it up.

As an aside, if you have `extern "C"` in the declaration (prototype) of a function in the header file then you shouldn't need it on the definition (implementation). It may keep your code tidier - in general I don't use `extern "C"` at all.

Comment: Thank you Tom for your quick reply.  I have already followed your post to set up the project in visual studio though there were some of the optional parts that I could not find e.g. I was unable to see C/C++ -> General in my project's properties to add the CUDA include files to the search path.  I have included cuda.rules and the runtime library so I am still stuck.

Comment: Scratch the part about not finding C/C++ -> General.  Apparently it is there.

Comment: If you only have .cu files in your project then Visual Studio will not invoke the C/C++ compiler (cl.exe) directly so the C/C++ category in Project Properties won't be there. That's ok though, since none of the settings in there would be relevant! So if you only have .cu files, then ignore the C/C++ settings.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a problem with calling my CUDA functions from my C++ code. I decided to use extern and followed some tutorials online.

After reading your code, there is one thing I did differently. Instead of doing an include of the cuda file (crowdsim.cuh) I forward declared the function in my C++ code. I rewrote the extern declarations in my C++ file, and compiled the code, and this time it worked.

Here's the tutorial I referred. Hope it helps

http://codereflect.com/2008/09/29/how-to-call-cuda-programs-from-a-cc-application/

Comment: And about the part where you couldn't find C/C++... that happened to me once when i had a project that consisted of only .cu files. I'm not sure but that maybe the reason.

Comment: See my comment on the other answer about .cu only projects.

Answer (score 0):

This is true of course only if you don't have mixed c/c++ and Cuda files, in this case the NVCC can genrate some objects for regular linkage and some code in the GPU assembly object language.