# What is the compiler seeing with this macro?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, stringification

Consider this:

```
  #define STRINGIFY(A) #A
```

If I then later write:

```
 STRINGIFY(hello)
```

Is the compiler actually seeing this:

```
 #hello
```

I think it is that additional hash in front of `#A` that is confusing me.

Comment: searching for `[C] stringify` on SO gives plenty of answers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use the preprocessor to convert code into a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284403/use-the-preprocessor-to-convert-code-into-a-string)

Comment: _"closed as not real question"_? What's not clear? Maybe it's a duplicate, but the question is really clear: it's in the title.

Comment: I have to agree, the question seems quite clear with no room for ambiguity

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the compiler will put the argument between quotes, resulting in this:

```
"hello"
```

However, beware that macro substitution doesn't take place near `#` and `##`, so if you really need to stringify the argument (*even if it's another macro*) it's better to write two macros, the first one to expand the argument and the other one to add quotes:

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY_AUX(x)
#define STRINGIFY_AUX(x) #x
```

Or more generally, if you're compiler supports variadic macros (introduced in C99):

```
#define STRINGIFY(...) STRINGIFY_AUX(__VA_ARGS__)
#define STRINGIFY_AUX(...) #__VA_ARGS__
```

If you really need a function-like macro that paste a `#` at the beginning of the argument, I think you need it to generate a string (otherwise you'd make an invalid token for the compiler), so you could simple generate two string literals that the compiler will "paste":

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRINGIFY(...) STRINGIFY_AUX(__VA_ARGS__)
#define STRINGIFY_AUX(...) #__VA_ARGS__

int main(void)
{
  puts(STRINGIFY(#) STRINGIFY(hello));
}
```

The `main` body will look like this in the preprocessor output:

```
puts("#" "hello");
```

I hope this is not an obscure corner of the preprocessor that results in undefined behavior, but it shouldn't be a problem since we're not generating another preprocessor instruction.

Answer (score 17):

What the compiler sees is this:

```
"hello"
```

The hash is preprocessor-only token.

Single hash stringifies the argument.

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
STRINGIFY(hello)
```

gets replaced by

```
"hello"
```

Double hash concatenates the tokens:

```
#define CAT(a, b) a##b
#define _STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) _STRINGIFY(x)
STRINGIFY(CAT(hello,world))
```

gets replaced by this:

```
_STRINGIFY(helloworld)
```

and then by this:

```
"helloworld"
```

EDIT:
As Pubby pointed out, the example was wrong, the macro replacement doesn't work that way, but now I corrected it.

Comment: Well that's great, can you explain what exactly the hash does to the OP, to make this answer somewhat useful?

Comment: i agree i am still confused. the second hash is then also getting interpreted by preprocessor, so essentially the preprocessor is doing two interpretations when STRINGIFY is used?

Comment: @andrewx The hash is only to tell preprocessor "stringify this".

Comment: Temporary -1 as `STRINGIFY(CAT(hello,world))` does not expand to `"helloworld"`. The rules are weird for argument expansion, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8754665/964135

Answer (score 10):

You can test it yourself using the `-E` (*) flag (with gcc/g++):

### test.cpp

```
#define STRINGIFY(A) #A

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    STRINGIFY(hello);
    return 0;
}
```

Output of `g++ test.cpp -E`

```
# 1 "test.cpp"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "test.cpp"


int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    "hello";
    return 0;
}
```

<sub>(*): `If you use the -E option, nothing is done except preprocessing.` - [GCC Options Controlling the Preprocessor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Found good, simple explanation of using hash in preprocessor here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/