# Multiply defined standard allocator

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, cuda

I am trying to compile a C++ DLL with VC++2008. I already compiled it correctly with VC++2010, but with VC++2008, I get the following error:

```
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP90.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: unsigned short * __cdecl std::allocator<unsigned short>::allocate(unsigned __int64)" (?allocate@?$allocator@G@std@@QEAAPEAG_K@Z) already defined in cuda.obj
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP90.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: unsigned short * __cdecl std::allocator<unsigned short>::allocate(unsigned __int64)" (?allocate@?$allocator@G@std@@QEAAPEAG_K@Z) already defined in cuda.obj
```

`cuda.obj` is compiled using `nvcc`, but as far as I can tell, I gave nvcc the exact same compiler options than for the other files.

What can I do, and where could this error come from?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you use the same runtime library, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046228/how-do-i-start-a-new-cuda-project-in-visual-studio-2008/2047892#2047892) for how to set up the projects. Specifically, make sure you use /MTd for both the CUDA build rule and the standard C/C++ build (or /MT).